# Bootstrap Tabs - Not displaying content when clicking on tab

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm working locally in VS Code and trying to get Bootstrap tabs to work. I am using Bootstrap 4. I've tried several examples and different ways of doing this to no avail. I'm pretty new to developing so I'm not pretending to "know it all":)
Hopefully by looking at my code someone who does this a lot will go "here you go! your forgetting.......

Here is the code in my .html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Tabs</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./twitch.css">
        <script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./twitch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#featured" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Featured</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Info</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="featured">Featured Info</div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to include bootstrap js files.

From the docs:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! adding a reference to the bootstrap JS is returning expected behaviour!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! I added a reference to the bootstrap JS and the tabs seem to be working now! Thank you very much Ivan!

Below is the code that is working in !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Twitchi Feed</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./twitch.css">
        <script src="./js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./twitch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#featured" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Featured</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">Home Info</div>
                <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="featured">Featured Info</div>
            </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```